# Change logon credential of a Windows Service

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-services

When creating a Windows service, using [`CreateService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function we can specify what logon credentials will be used for the service (last two parameters of function).

How can we change the logon credentials after the service is registered? Which Windows API to use?

With "Log On" tab in service property, we can change the user details the service would run under. I believe Services MMC doesn't delete and create the service again just for credential change.

Comment: look for [ChangeServiceConfig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681987(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Oh! I was looking into `ChangeServiceConfig2`, assuming it is super set. Please add your response as answer, so that i can accept it. I will edit your answer if you're unwilling to give example! :)